# Blackberry RichTextField preferred height during layout

Tags: blackberry

This is using the Backberry JDK (5.0 if needed).

I have a custom Manager that contains a RichTextField.  I want the height of the field to vary by the amount of text in the RichTextField.

The sublayout code looks like this (rtf is a RichTextField object):

```
    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
    int h = rtf.getPreferredHeight();
    setExtent(Display.getWidth(), h);
    layoutChild(rtf, Display.getWidth(), h);
    setPositionChild(rtf, 0, 0);

    setExtent(Display.getWidth(), h);
}
```

The call to rtf.getPreferredHeight always returns the same value, no matter how much text (and therefore how many lines on the screen).

Any clues on how to get the height of a RichTextField when the content and width are known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, as soon as I posted it I figured out the answer.  Query the control after calling layoutChild.

This fixed it:

```
    int h = rtf.getPreferredHeight();
    layoutChild(rtf, Display.getWidth(), h);

    h = rtf.getHeight();

    setPositionChild(rtf, 0, 0);

    setExtent(Display.getWidth(), h);
```

I would have deleted the question but maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
RichTextField deviceId = new RichTextField() {
    protected void setExtent(int width, int height) {
        super.setExtent(Display.getWidth() - 30, 25);
    }
};
```

This solved my problem for setting `height` and `width` for `RichTextField` when you don't want to write separate class for it.